# When iterating through a map, some values seem to be skipped

Tags: java, hashmap, iteration

Here I have a program that is creating a map of stars and planets. It does so by:

1. Creating a multi-dimensional array of 'indexes' with `indexMap[][]`. Which simply means for every x and y coordinate on the map, it is given a number that counts onward from 1. `e.g. indexMap[0][0] = 1, indexMap[1][0] = 2. indexMap[2][0] = 3... etc.`
2. Then we create our "Quadrants" which are essentially solar systems of planets and a star in random locations. This will find a suitable random location within the map, then it will scan 20 indexes in the surrounding area giving them values. These values come in the form of a `Map<Integer, Systems> map`, Systems being a java class that stores values of the quadrant number, type of body (i.e. planet) and its x and y coordinates, and the Integer is the current index from the `indexMap[][]` that is being checked.

This all seems fine, but when I iterate through all of my Systems (around line 48) I get a problem. According to the console log below, of the 6 stars and 42 planets that were created, only 5 planets and 1 star were found when iterating through. Furthermore it is good to note that they are all apart of the same quadrant and even then, if you were to count the number of planets that are actually in quadrant 6, not all of the bodies were found of that quadrant.

So am I iterating through incorrectly, or is there another issue i haven't foreseen?

**CODE**

```
public class Systems 
{
    public float x, y;
    public int body, quadNum;

    public Systems(int quadNum, int body, float x, float y)
    {
        this.quadNum = quadNum;
        this.body = body;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}

public class UniverseGen 
{   
    private float chanceNum, systemChance = 0.02f, planetChance = 0.1f;

    private Map<Integer, Systems> map = new HashMap<Integer, Systems>();

    public int[][] indexMap;

    private int indexWidth, indexHeight;
    public int quadNum = 1;
    private int numOfStars = 0, numOfPlanets = 0;

    private int space = 0, star = 1, planet = 2;

    public Map<Integer, Systems> initMap(int width, int height)
    {   
        indexWidth = width / BodyManager.TILE_WIDTH;
        indexHeight = height / BodyManager.TILE_HEIGHT;

        indexMap = new int[indexWidth][indexHeight];

        //Create Index Array
        System.out.println("Creating Index Array...");
        int indexCount = 0;
        for (int y=0; y<indexMap[0].length; y++)
        {
            for (int x=0; x<indexMap.length; x++)
            {
                indexMap[x][y] = indexCount;
                indexCount++;
            }
        }

        //Create Quadrants
        System.out.println("Creating Quadrants...");
        for (int y=0; y<indexHeight; y++)
        {
            for (int x=0; x<indexWidth; x++)
            {
                createQuadrants(x, y);
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Number of Stars: " + numOfStars);
        System.out.println("Number of Planets: " + numOfPlanets);

        for (Systems s : map.values())
        {
            if (s.body != 0)
            {
                System.out.println("Body: " + s.body + " Quadrant: " + s.quadNum + " x, y:" + s.x + ", " + s.y);
            }
        }

        return map;
    }

    private void createQuadrants(int x, int y)
    {
        int tileX = x * BodyManager.TILE_WIDTH;
        int tileY = y * BodyManager.TILE_HEIGHT;

        int planetCount = 0;

        if (x <= 0 || y <= 0 || x >= indexWidth || y >= indexHeight)
        {
            map.put(indexMap[x][y], new Systems(0, space, tileX, tileY));
        }
        else if (randomChance() <= systemChance && checkSystems(x, y))
        {

            System.out.println("Star: " + tileX + ", " + tileY + " Quad: " + quadNum);
            //Create Quadrant
            for (int i=-20; i<=20; i++)
            {
                for (int j=-20; j<=20; j++)
                {
                    //Surrounding tiles
                    int newX = (tileX + (i * BodyManager.TILE_WIDTH));
                    int newY = (tileY + (j * BodyManager.TILE_HEIGHT));

                    //If outside world boundaries, skip
                    if (x + i <= 0 || y + j <= 0 || x + i >= indexWidth || y + j >= indexHeight) 
                        continue;
                    //Create star at origin of system
                    else if (i == 0 && j == 0)
                    {
                        map.put(indexMap[x + i][y + j], new Systems(quadNum, star, tileX, tileY));
                    }
                    //When checking one tile outside the origin, create space
                    else if (i >= -1 && i <= 1 && j >= -1 && j <= 1)
                        map.put(indexMap[x + i][y + j], new Systems(quadNum, space, newX, newY));
                    //If planet parameters work out, create planet
                    else if (i >= -6 && i <= 6 && j >= -6 && j <= 6 &&
                            planetCount <= 6 &&
                            randomChance() <= planetChance && 
                            checkPlanets(x, y))
                    {
                        System.out.println("Planet: " + newX + ", " + newY);
                        map.put(indexMap[x + i][y + j], new Systems(quadNum, planet, newX, newY));
                        planetCount++;
                        numOfPlanets++;
                    }   
                    //If none of these create space
                    else
                        map.put(indexMap[x + i][y + j], new Systems(quadNum, space, newX, newY));
                }
            }
            numOfStars++;
            quadNum++;
        }
        else
        {
            //Set to empty object
            map.put(indexMap[x][y], new Systems(0, space, tileX, tileY));
        }
    }


//Some code has been deleted to shorten this post
```

**This is the console output:**

```
Creating Index Array...
Creating Quadrants...
Star: 1000, 840 Quad: 1
Planet: 880, 880
Planet: 900, 940
Planet: 920, 840
Planet: 920, 900
Planet: 920, 920
Planet: 940, 740
Planet: 980, 900
Star: 900, 860 Quad: 2
Planet: 820, 860
Planet: 840, 820
Planet: 860, 860
Planet: 880, 820
Planet: 880, 980
Planet: 900, 940
Planet: 920, 900
Star: 1080, 860 Quad: 3
Planet: 980, 780
Planet: 980, 840
Planet: 1040, 760
Planet: 1040, 820
Planet: 1060, 920
Planet: 1080, 940
Planet: 1120, 740
Star: 900, 880 Quad: 4
Planet: 780, 880
Planet: 800, 880
Planet: 800, 980
Planet: 840, 960
Planet: 860, 960
Planet: 880, 820
Planet: 880, 920
Star: 1020, 880 Quad: 5
Planet: 900, 940
Planet: 920, 760
Planet: 920, 1000
Planet: 940, 760
Planet: 940, 800
Planet: 960, 840
Planet: 960, 960
Star: 1060, 1160 Quad: 6
Planet: 940, 1060
Planet: 940, 1080
Planet: 940, 1280
Planet: 980, 1060
Planet: 980, 1080
Planet: 1000, 1100
Planet: 1020, 1240
Number of Stars: 6
Number of Planets: 42
Body: 2 Quadrant: 6 x, y:940.0, 1060.0
Body: 2 Quadrant: 6 x, y:980.0, 1060.0
Body: 2 Quadrant: 6 x, y:940.0, 1080.0
Body: 2 Quadrant: 6 x, y:980.0, 1080.0
Body: 2 Quadrant: 6 x, y:1000.0, 1100.0
Body: 1 Quadrant: 6 x, y:1060.0, 1160.0
```

Comment: That's a lot of code to expect someone to read!

Comment: Yeah sorry about that, that's why i briefly tried to explain how it works at the start

Comment: I'll edit it and make it shorter

Comment: It looks like there's a problem with the way you use your indexMap in the map `put` calls.  It seems like your index map is based on the quadrants, but each time you create a quadrant you iterate over i and j values which you add to the quadrant coordinates, and that seems to overwrite the previous quadrants' values.  Thus in the iteration you see only the values from the last quadrant.

Comment: @aro_tech Thankyou for this comment, this has given me a good idea of possibly how to fix the problem. Hopefully it works :)

Answer (score 0):

I have found a fix for this issue. Thanks to @aro_tech for putting me on the right track.

I won't go into detail, but I had to access the quadrant number separately from the map itself and fix up some issues with my `checkSystems()` method which has been edited off this post.